# Python Logging UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, error-logging

Logging error I can not print id to log

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\NLP_Research\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1028, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\NLP_Research\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uff1a' in position 80: character maps to <undefined>
```

Call stack:

File "preprocess.py", line 173, in

```
test_out = get_out(processor, './input/data/test.txt', args, id2label, 'test')
```

File "preprocess.py", line 149, in get_out

```
out = convert_examples_to_features(examples, args.max_seq_len, args.bert_dir)
```

File "preprocess.py", line 119, in convert_examples_to_features

```
tokenizer=tokenizer,
```

File "preprocess.py", line 93, in convert_bert_example

```
logger.info(f"ids：{ids}")
logger.info(f"ids：{ids}")
Message: 'ids：[165, 175, 73, 79]'
Arguments: ()
```

Comment: Hosw did this: https://unicodeplus.com/U+FF1A get into `ids`?  Is it the `:` in `'ids : [...]`? Where is your data from?

Comment: In any case the solution is simple: don't log `ids` before you've sanitised it.  Or, probably, don't log it at all---there's dubious value in logging data, as opposed to state messages ('decoding xyz').

Comment: thank you, I solved this issue by add `encoding='utf-8'` in `file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path, encoding='utf-8')`